Orthogonal function basis with sparse product and derivative representation
If $\phi_n(x)$ is an orthogonal basis, then the product ought to be representable as
$$ \phi_m(x) \phi_n(x) = \sum_q M_{mnq} \phi_q(x) $$
However in most cases (with the exception of Fourier/Exponential) I've seen (Legendre) the hypermatrix $M_{mnq}$ is typically dense on $q$. In the case of Chebyshev, the product is sparse but is the differentiation that becomes dense.
Question: Are there other orthogonal bases for which both the product and differentiation representation is sparse? (besides the Fourier functions, which only work on periodic boundaries)

Why don't Chebyshev polynomials work? It doesn't look like the matrix is dense in $q$ to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Products_of_Chebyshev_polynomials

@TrevorNorton my bad, I should've clarified that the problem with Chebyshev is that the differentiation operation is dense. I edited the question

@TrevorNorton actually no, Chebyshev is indeed dense in product, because of the term $T_{|m - n|}$ in $T_m T_n$, basically the coefficient for $T_1$ in the product expansion will have coefficients of the form $a_{m} b_{m \pm 1}$ for all $m$, and so on

Not sure I understand what you mean. The product $T_mT_n$ is a linear combination of only two other basis functions. Regardless, it doesn’t appear to be the example you are looking for with respect to its derivatives.
